# Sublime Text 3 Unexpected token ILLEGAL in js files

Tags: javascript, encoding, sublimetext3

It's a bit weird what I'm having with sublime text 3.

Whenever I edit a JavaScript file with Sublime I get `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error.

So I reopen the file with vim then just rewrite it as it is and it works, no error. But whenever a change is made using Sublime, it adds automatically illegal chars at the end of the file.

This happens only for JavaScript files.

I made sure encoding is UTF-8, and I make sure to use the "reopen file with encoding" option.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answear, it's a vagrant problem, I had to add `EnableSendFile off` in apache conf

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html